# Is this necessary that $k$ be algebraic close field in this theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, field-theory, examples-counterexamples

let $k$ be algebraic close field and
$A=k\left[x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}\right]$

for any subset $Y \subseteq \mathbf{A}^{n}_k$,define the ideal of $Y$ in $A$ by

$
I(Y)=\left\{f \in A \mid f(P)=0 \text { for all } P \in Y\right\}$

and $Z(T)=\left\{P \in \mathbf{A}^{n}_k \mid f(P)=0\right.$ for all $\left.f \in T\right\}$

Theorem : **For any ideal $a \subseteq A, I(Z(a))=\sqrt{a},$ the radical of $\mathfrak{a} .$**

> Is this necessary that $k$  be algebraic close field in the above theorem ?

Comment: This depends on what $\Bbb A^n_k$ means for you. What is your definition?

Comment: @KReiser .  We define affine $n$ -space over $k$ denoted $\mathbf{A}_{k}^{n}$ or simply $\mathbf{A}^{n}$, to be the set of all $n$ -tuples of elements of $k$.

Comment: Then Christoph's answer below is correct. If you had instead taken $\Bbb A^n_k=\operatorname{Spec} k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, then the claim would be true without assumptions on the field $k$. This is why it's important to specify whether you're working with "classical" varieties or schemes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Take $k=\mathbb R$ and $\mathfrak a=(x^2+1)\subset k[x]$ for example. We have have $Z(\mathfrak a)=\varnothing$ and $I(Z(\mathfrak a)) = k[x]$, which is not the radical of $\mathfrak a$.

Comment: why $I(Z(a)) \neq \sqrt{a} $ ? what is $\sqrt{a}$ ?

Comment: @amirbahadory $\mathfrak{a}$ is a prime ideal, so $\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}=\mathfrak{a}$

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom . i can't show why $Z((x^2+1))=\emptyset $ ?

Comment: @amirbahadory For $x\in\mathbb R$ we always have $x^2\ge 0$. Hence, $x^2+1\ge 1$ so in particular $x^2+1\neq 0$. The polynomial doesn't have any real roots.

Comment: i know that $x^2+1=0$ has no root in real number but why for any polynomial $f \in (x^2+1)$ we have $f(x) \neq 0$ for all real $x$ ?

Comment: @amirbahadory We don't need that. $Z((x^2+1))$ is the set of all common roots of all polynomials in $(x^2+1)$. Since $x^2+1$ is one of the elements and it doesn't have any roots, there are no common roots to all elements of the ideal.

Comment: @amirbahadory also, to add to Christoph's comment, the condition you've written is in fact false. for instance, $0\in (x^2+1)$, and the $0$ polynomial has a root at _every_ real number. for a less trivial example, consider the polynomial $x(x^2+1)\in (x^2+1)$, which has the root $0\in\mathbb{R}$